# How can a separate terminal be opened to display execution for each Task?

Tags: java, terminal, output, task

I am using the ScheduledService class to run separate Tasks and would like to open a new terminal for each Task so its execution can be displayed, for example, the output from `exception.printStackTrace();` and `System.out.println();`

Comment: Not really, I'm afraid.

Comment: I think the only way would be to run the task as a subprocess with its own console.

Comment: There is a single Standard output stream for a given process. But you can write to as many files as you want to Why don't you log to files instead of the console?